# BigQuery - Rank by multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

forgive me if i've written this out all wrong or have laid it out wrong.

I want a ranking column which ranks a visitors order_id by date and fullvisitorid, like below. Is this possible? If so, what would the line of code look like?

| date | fullvisitorID | order_id | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20201127 | 2148490690588403919 | MUK105556400 | 1 |
| 20201128 | 2148490690588403919 | MUK105556401 | 2 |
| 20201129 | 2148490690588403919 | MUK105606555 | 3 |
| 20201127 | 6444290669077908463 | MUK105521707 | 1 |
| 20201128 | 6444290669077908463 | MUK105633922 | 2 |
| 20201129 | 6444290669077908463 | MUK105630521 | 3 |

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT date,
  fullVisitorId,
  order_id,
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    fullVisitorId,
    hits.TRANSACTION.transactionId AS order_id
  FROM
    `table_name`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    date BETWEEN '20201127'
    AND '20201130'
    AND hits.TRANSACTION.transactionId IS NOT NULL
    AND geoNetwork. country = 'United Kingdom'
    AND fullVisitorId IN ('2148490690588403919',
      '6444290669077908463'))
ORDER BY
  2 ASC,
  1 ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See exxample below

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '20201127' date, 2148490690588403919 fullvisitorID,'MUK105556400' order_id union all
  select '20201128', 2148490690588403919,'MUK105556401' union all
  select '20201129', 2148490690588403919,'MUK105606555' union all
  select '20201127', 6444290669077908463,'MUK105521707' union all
  select '20201128', 6444290669077908463,'MUK105633922' union all
  select '20201129', 6444290669077908463,'MUK105630521' 
)
select *,
  rank() over(partition by fullvisitorID order by date, order_id) rank
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]